# Multicast not working at Windows 10 PC. How to Enable multicast at Local LAN at Windows 10

Tags: wireshark, multicast, lan

I can multicast at 224.0.0.1 and my all others local LAN PCs can listen the stream. 
But when I multicast at other multicast IP like: 224.0.0.130, no LAN PCs can listen that. Though I can get at wireshark in source PC.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you enabled promiscuous mode in Wireshark?

Answer (score 7):

There are several reasons not to work multicast in windows 10. I have solved it by following 2 steps:

1. **Interface Metric:** From network settings, go to advance option and uncheck Automatic metric and set Interface matric a number. Lower the prior.

[image: IP Settings]

2. **Change C# code:**
   By default, multicast send data to loopback interface. Hence need to specify which interface you want to use, means which ip you want use to send the multicast stream (ie. At which network you want to send multicast).

Here’s a sample C# code:

```
                  m_Socket.SetSocketOption(
                 SocketOptionLevel.IP,
                 SocketOptionName.MulticastInterface,
                 IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.104").GetAddressBytes()
                );
```

M_Socket is the socket to send the stream and “192.168.0.104” is the interface ip at which network I want to send the stream.

By following above, Now I can send multicast successfully.